# How to obfuscate or disguise a command?

Tags: command-line

I run some long running tasks on a shared Ubuntu server. When I run htop, my task is completely visible e.g.

```
python path/a_named_script input1 input2
```

Is there a way to disguise this command (without renaming the actual script and inputs) so that htop shows it as something else? e.g.

```
python a_long_running_task
```

Answer (score 0):

`htop` settings (F2 or shift-s) only allows altering the top part.

> (without renaming the actual script and inputs)

No. It will show the command as is, with parameters.